# angular 2 Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined

Tags: angular

Now the {{article.}} properties all work fine and display what they are in the web page, why is article.comments (at bottom of html) saying article is undefined when it is the pages input? Thanks.

Aricle.cs model
    import {Comment} from './comment';

```
export class Article {
  id : number; 
  isanon : boolean; 
  title: string;
  link: string;
  text: string; 
  subverse : string;
  userID : string;  
  votes: number;
  comments : Comment[]; 

  constructor(title: string, link: string, subverse : string, text : string, userID : string, votes?: number) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.text = text; 
    this.subverse = subverse; 
    this.userID = userID; 
    this.votes = votes || 0;
    this.comments = new Array<Comment>(); 
  }

  log() : void{
    console.log("Title: " + this.title + " Link: " + this.link + " subverse: " + this.subverse); 
  }

  domain(): string {
    try {
      return this.link; 
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  voteUp(): void {
    this.votes += 1;
  }

  voteDown(): void {
    this.votes -= 1;
  }


}
```

articlefullpage.component.html

```
<div class="ui large segment"> 
<div class="field">
  Article Title: {{article.title}}
</div> 
<div class="field">
  Article Link: <a href="{{article.link}}">{{article.link}}</a>
</div> 
<div class="field">
  User Text: {{article.text}}
</div> 
<div class="field">
  Subverse: {{article.subverse}}
</div> 
<div class="field">
  Votes: {{article.votes}}
</div> 
</div> 
<br/><br/> 

<div class="ui large segment">
Add comment 
<form class="form ui large segment">
<textarea rows="10" cols="10" #comment>

</textarea>
  <!-- added this button -->
  <button (click)="addComment(comment)"  
          class="ui positive right floated button">  
    Submit link  
  </button>  
</form> 
</div> 

<app-comment-tree [commentTree]="article.comments"></app-comment-tree>
```

articlefullpage.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import { Article } from '../models/article';
import {Location} from '@angular/common'; 
import {AppServiceHackersPulse} from '../services/app.service.hackerspulse'; 
import {User} from '../models/user';
import {Comment} from '../models/comment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articlefullpage',
  templateUrl: './app/articlefullpage/articlefullpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/articlefullpage/articlefullpage.component.css'],
  host: {
    class: 'row'
  },
  providers: [AppServiceHackersPulse]
})
export class ArticleFullPageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() article : Article; 
  service : AppServiceHackersPulse; 
  user : User; 
  Id : string; 

  constructor(private location : Location, private hpService: AppServiceHackersPulse)
  {
    this.service = hpService; 
    this.Id = location.path().split('/')[2]; 

    this.service.GetUser().subscribe( (data) => {
      this.user = data; 
    }); 
  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

  getArticle() : Article
  {
    return this.article; 
  }

  addComment(comment : HTMLInputElement)
  {
    var c : Comment = new Comment(0,0,this.user.id,comment.value,Number(this.Id));
    this.article.comments.push(c); 
    console.log("comment: " + comment.value); 
  }

}
```

Full error

```
core.umd.js:2837EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in app/articlefullpage/articlefullpage.component.html:33:18 caused by: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined
    at CompiledTemplate.
```

Comment: Full source: https://github.com/claysmith/hackerspulse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First port of call is put an *ngIf on the offending tag:

```
<app-comment-tree *ngIf="article" [commentTree]="article.comments"></app-comment-tree>
```

The view could be trying to access the article property before it has been initialized.

Comment: Yea, this is it. Is there something like ngIf for the entire page? Or do I have to litter things that use articles with *ngIf="article"

Comment: You could generally also write article?.comments which is checking if articles is defined and only then proceeds funding the comments

Answer (score 0):

Where is your component `app-comment-tree`? The problem is that `article` is not defined in that custom component.
You have to import the class from that component and access it like `ArticleFullPageComponent.article.comments` in the template `articlefullpage.component.html` if it is defined as a public property.

Or you can define it in that custom component that you have not posted.

Hope it helps.